# MATLAB Subtract Matrices More Efficiently

Tags: matlab, matrix, subtraction, bsxfun

I am subtracting two matrices from each other. dataClim is the average data of each month (12 months) over a 30 year period. dataAll is the daily data over 1257 days. I need to subtract the average monthly data from the daily data of each month from 20100101 to 20130611 (t = 1:31 is January, t = 32-57 is February, all the way to December, then 363:393 is January again).

This code works, but I was wondering if there was any way to make it more efficient and less tedious. I don't know how I would write a loop because the months vary in number of days from 28 to 31.

```
% Create new array in which data_Anom is the anomaly 
% dataAnom = dataAll - dataClim 

% January
dataAnom_1 = bsxfun(@minus, dataAll(:,:,[1:31, 363:393, 728:758, 1094:1124]), dataClim(:,:,1));

% February
dataAnom_2 = bsxfun(@minus, dataAll(:,:,[32:57, 394:421, 759:787, 1125:1152]), dataClim(:,:,2));

% March
dataAnom_3 = bsxfun(@minus, dataAll(:,:,[58:88, 422:452, 788:818, 1153:1183]), dataClim(:,:,3));

% April
dataAnom_4 = bsxfun(@minus, dataAll(:,:,[89:118, 453:482, 819:848, 1184:1213]), dataClim(:,:,4));

% May
dataAnom_5 = bsxfun(@minus, dataAll(:,:,[119:148, 483:513, 849:879, 1214:1244]), dataClim(:,:,5));

% June 
dataAnom_6 = bsxfun(@minus, dataAll(:,:,[149:178, 514:543, 880:909, 1245:1255]), dataClim(:,:,6));

% July
dataAnom_7 = bsxfun(@minus, dataAll(:,:,[179:209, 544:574, 910:940]), dataClim(:,:,7));

% August
dataAnom_8 = bsxfun(@minus, dataAll(:,:,[210:240, 575:605, 941:971]), dataClim(:,:,8));

% September
dataAnom_9 = bsxfun(@minus, dataAll(:,:,[241:270, 606:635, 972:1001]), dataClim(:,:,9));

% October
dataAnom_10 = bsxfun(@minus, dataAll(:,:,[271:301, 636:666, 1002:1032]), dataClim(:,:,10));

% November
dataAnom_11 = bsxfun(@minus, dataAll(:,:,[302:331, 667:696, 1033:1062]), dataClim(:,:,11));

% December
dataAnom_12 = bsxfun(@minus, dataAll(:,:,[332:362, 697:727, 1063:1093]), dataClim(:,:,12));

% Concatenate the seperate Anomalies
dataAnom = cat(3, dataAnom_1, dataAnom_2, dataAnom_3, dataAnom_4, dataAnom_5, dataAnom_6, dataAnom_7, dataAnom_8, dataAnom_9, dataAnom_10, dataAnom_11, dataAnom_12);

clear dataAnom_*
```

One idea I had was to concatenate the days for each month together first and then create dataAnom for each month. It's probably even slower.

```
% Concatenation days below to each month in dataAll into dataMon so that each month is placed together. This
% makes it easier to do the anomaly subtraction later.

dataMon = cat(3, dataAll(:,:,1:31), dataAll(:,:,363:393), dataAll(:,:,728:758) , dataAll(:,:,1094:1124),... % January
    dataAll(:,:,32:57), dataAll(:,:,394:421), dataAll(:,:,759:787), dataAll(:,:,1125:1152),... % February
    dataAll(:,:,58:88), dataAll(:,:,422:452), dataAll(:,:,788:818), dataAll(:,:,1153:1183),... % March
    dataAll(:,:,89:118), dataAll(:,:,453:482), dataAll(:,:,819:848), dataAll(:,:,1184:1213),... % April
    dataAll(:,:,119:148), dataAll(:,:,483:513), dataAll(:,:,849:879), dataAll(:,:,1214:1244),... % May
    dataAll(:,:,149:178), dataAll(:,:,514:543), dataAll(:,:,880:909), dataAll(:,:,1245:1255),... % June. Last entry goes up to 20130611, not the full month
    dataAll(:,:,179:209), dataAll(:,:,544:574), dataAll(:,:,910:940),... % July
    dataAll(:,:,210:240), dataAll(:,:,575:605), dataAll(:,:,941:971),... % August
    dataAll(:,:,241:270), dataAll(:,:,606:635), dataAll(:,:,972:1001),... % Sept
    dataAll(:,:,271:301), dataAll(:,:,636:666), dataAll(:,:,1002:1032),... % Oct
    dataAll(:,:,302:331), dataAll(:,:,667:696), dataAll(:,:,1033:1062),... % Nov
    dataAll(:,:,332:362), dataAll(:,:,697:727), dataAll(:,:,1063:1093)); % Dec

% Create dataAnom
dataAnom1 = bsxfun(@minus, dataAll(:,:,1:124), dataClim(:,:,1);
dataAnom2 = bsxfun(@minus, dataAll(:,:,125:238:), dataClim(:,:,1);
.
.
.
dataAnom12 = ...

% Combine
dataAnom = cat(3, dataAnom1, dataAnom2, dataAnom3,....);
```

Comment: As an aside, why don't you use a better matrix structure?  i.e. `12x31xNumOfYears`?  For the months that aren't 31 days you can use `NaN` to represented the missing day.

Comment: Why is February from 32-57? If your data is not structured properly, everything will have to be hardcoded, and that would suck.

Comment: February is 28 days or 29 days. The data simply lists the days one after another. The x and y of the matrix is lat and lon across the globe and z is the number of days from 20100101 to 20130611. I don't think it's a good idea to just add in NaN to make each month 31 days or something.

Comment: @user2258883 see my answer for a better understanding of what I mean.

Comment: Your February seems to have neither 28 nor 29 days, but 26 days... Also note that the first year has 362 days. How's that possible? Do all corresponding months in different years have the same number of days at least?

Comment: Where does `dataAll` come from?  Are you able to alter the way that it's populated?

Comment: Thanks. I was missing data. I will add that in.

Comment: @ KronoS dataAll is a data set that was created from another script. It's size is 1437x159x125.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I still hold onto the fact that you should refactor your data, you can also use the power of `datenum` to help you.  The following will make your life a lot easier, than trying to manually enter the days:

```
clear all; clc;

% Init Data
dataAll = rand(1437,159,1258);

% Starting date of sampling.  Note that this assumes each day there was a sample, and only one sample
startDate = datenum('01-01-2010');
dateList = [0:1257] + startDate;
[yr, mn, ~, ~, ~, ~] = datevec(dateList);

% extract data depending on month that sample was taken
jan = dataAll(:,:,mn == 1);
feb = dataAll(:,:,mn == 2);
mar = dataAll(:,:,mn == 3);
... % and so forth
```

This should get the desired results you're looking for.  From here you can do your resulting calculations:

```
dataAnom_1 = bsxfun(@minus, jan, dataClim(:,:,1));
```

---

With your updated information from the comments you can do the following to separate your data according to month and year:

```
jan2010 = dataAll(:,:,(mn == 1 & yr == 2010);
feb2010 = dataAll(:,:,(mn == 2 & yr == 2010);
... % and so forth
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. But I found that I can't do it completely like this because this places all January's together, then all Feb (it's my fault for not realizing that before). That ruins the order of the days.

Comment: @user2258883 what do you mean by it "ruins the order of the days"?

Comment: `jan = dataAll(:,:,mn == 1);` puts all the January's together. So when I do `dataAnom_1 = bsxfun(@minus, jan, dataClim(:,:,1));` later on, I end up subtracting all the January's from dataClim. When I combine dataAnom_1, dataAnom_2, etc. back into a large matrix, it end up being wrong because I end up graphing the anomalies of 4 different Januaries, then 4 February's, etc. together instead of graphing January 2010, February 2010, .... January 2011, February 2011, ...

Comment: @user2258883 I've updated the answer, however, this is only confirming my original answer that you really need to figure out a better structure for storing and manipulating your data.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to rethink how you approaching the way your structuring your data here.  Instead of creating massive single row arrays (`dataAnom1` and `dataAll`) I would use a better structured matrix.

At it's simplest you could used a scheme like this:  `31x12xNumYears` which would produce something like this:

```
Data = NaN(31x12xNumYears); % Blank Init
Data(1:31,1,1) = Rand(31,1); % January's populated values
Data(1:28,2,1) = Rand(28,1); % February's populated values
... % and so forth
```

The advantage here is that matrix operations is far easier to do, and you have a better understanding of what the data actually represents.  For example, given that dataClim is the monthy average over 30 years (matrix should be `12x30`) and dataAll is the daily reading (matrix should be `31x12x30`)  you can do the following:

```
subValues = NaN(31,12,30);
for yr = 1:30
    for mn = 1:12
        subValues(1:31,mn,yr) = dataAll(1:31,mn,yr) - dataClim(mn,yr);
    end
end
```

---

With the added information that you've given me, I think this is the type of structure that you might be looking for: `days x months x years x 3` where three represents the lat, long, and dataValue of your data.  So for example:

```
test = rand(31,12,30,3);
lat = test(1:end,1:end,1:end,1); 
long = test(1:end,1:end,1:end,2);
data = test(1:end,1:end,1:end,3);
```

Comment: The thing is that my dataAll contains data for each lat and lon point across the globe so I can't change it without losing count of what point on the globe each cell corresponds to. Maybe I'm just not understanding what you are saying, but I'm not sure how I can restructure it to make it easier to do.

Comment: @user2258883 just to clarify, instead of it being a single value for each day, it's a lat and lon value?

Comment: The lat and lon values are in a different matrix. X is a 1437x159 matrix with 1:360 (long) going down the first column and repeating for all columns. Y is the same size with -89.5 to -50 (latitude South) going across the first row and repeating down all the rows. dataAll (1437x159x1258) is the data that corresponds to those points across 1258 days (my indexes above are wrong since you pointed out I was missing two days in Feb. and the indexes were based on not having those two days). So dataAll(1,1,1) would be the sea ice concentration at 1 (lon), -89.5 (lat), day 1 (20100101).

Comment: @user2258883 Ok I have a better understanding of what your data looks like, but I still suggest going back to the source of this data, and refactoring it to better suite your needs.  Working with this, is going to be a pain in the way that it is.

Comment: I think there may be a typo at the top. The data for February should be stored in `Data(1:29,2,1)`, right?

Comment: @Schorsch not unless it's a leap year.  None the less it's just an example.

Comment: My comment included two changes to the line, I'm sorry. I wasn't actually referring to the question of 28 vs 29 days (we are on the same page here), but the fact that the second dimension in `Data` should increase from 1 to 2.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you do

```
% January
dataAnom1 = bsxfun(@minus, dataAll(:,:,[1:31 363:393 728:758 1094:1124]), dataClim(:,:,1));
```

? I think this is the same.

And if so, then you can do

```
dataAnom1=zeros(size(dataAll,1),size(dataAll,2), 128*12);
for v=1:12
    dataAnom1(:,:,1+((v-1)*128:v*128)) = bsxfun(@minus, dataAll(:,:,[1:31 363:393 728:758 1094:1124]+(v-1*32)), dataClim(:,:,v));
end
```

(Indexing might be a little off)

Comment: Oh, looks like I just forgot brackets when I tried this before. Thanks.

Comment: The thing is that each month has either 31 or 30 days and Feb has 28 or 29 days. I don't know how to put that into consideration in the code.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Yes, it can be awkward working with months like this. You could potentially put each month's info into a 12-element cell and use vector expression on the data in the cell? E.g. `MonthData = cell(12,1); MonthData{1}=dataAll(:,:,1:31);`, and then use `bsxfun(@minus,MonthData{1},dataClim(:,:,1));` You could then wrap those in structs or cells for years, if appropriate: `Years = struct(4); Years(1).year=2009; Years(1).Data = MonthData;`

Comment: @user2258883 just as a caution, working with cells and doing operations can be a bit tricky.